# How to create pdf document with bookmarks and internal links in node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf

Please suggest node.js libraries to generate pdf document with bookmarks, internal links and barchart.

Thanks in advance,
Anoop Xaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit) which support:

1. Bookmarks
2. Internal links
3. HTML5 canvas-like API

Comment: Thank you Avissar. Can you please share helpful links to create bookmarks using pdfkit.

Comment: Here is the source code on how to create PDFrefence https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/master/lib/reference.coffee

Comment: I know this was answered a long time ago, but how do you do internal links. By that I mean how can I create a link in the text that goes to an internal bookmark?